# $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p},\sqrt[3]{q})= \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}\cdot \sqrt[3]{q})$ ??

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $p,q$ be primes, $p≠q$, then I have to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p},\sqrt[3]{q})= \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}\cdot \sqrt[3]{q})$

So far I've tried a lot of things with minimal polynomials and bases, but I'm far from any argument that I find sufficient.

This is an example from my algebra course, first chapter about field extension. So far we know about basic definitions, minimal polynomials and their properties, algebraic elements and algebraic fields.

Could someone maybe give me a hint about how to proceed? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}\cdot\sqrt[3]{q}) \subset \mathbb{q}(\sqrt{p},\sqrt[3]{q})$ should be clear. So you can for example show that both extensions have the same degree. Or you can show that $\sqrt{p} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}\cdot\sqrt[3]{q})$ (how does that then imply equality?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $K =  \Bbb Q(\sqrt{p}\sqrt[3]{q})$ and $\alpha = \sqrt{p}\sqrt[3]{q}$. Then $\alpha^3/(pq) = \sqrt{p} \in K$ and $\alpha/\sqrt{p} = \sqrt[3]{q} \in K$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Well, afterwards it always seem sooo easy..

Comment: The implication $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p} \cdot \sqrt[3]{q}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p},\sqrt[3]{q})$ is trivial, since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p},\sqrt[3]{q})$ ist the smallest field that contains $\sqrt{p},\sqrt[3]{q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$, is also contains the product $\sqrt{p} \cdot \sqrt[3]{q}$

Comment: For the other inculsion: if I now look at the polynomials $f_1(X)=\frac{X^3}{pq}$ and $f_2(X)=\frac{X^4}{p^2q}, f_1,f_2 \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ then I see that $f_1(\sqrt{p} \cdot \sqrt[3]{q})=\sqrt{p} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p} \cdot \sqrt[3]{q})$ and $f_2(\sqrt{p} \cdot \sqrt[3]{q})=\sqrt[3]{q} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p} \cdot \sqrt[3]{q})$. Therefore  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p},\sqrt[3]{q}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p} \cdot \sqrt[3]{q})$ because $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p},\sqrt[3]{q})$ is the smallest field that contains $\sqrt{p},\sqrt[3]{q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$.
Thanks a lot benh and @DanielFischer